# How can I use two different strings in one placeholder?

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm having a lot of trouble with a question we have been given in class Re: Conditional Statements.

I'm struggling to comprehend how I can have two variables (`"year"` and `"s"`) being able to go into one `{}`.

I must display a person's age in years (having taken their year of birth):

> Work out which year the user was born in and display the appropriate
>   message from below
>
> ```
> <FirstName>, it is now <CurrentYear>, you are <Age> year old and so you were born in <YearOfBirth>.
>
> <FirstName>, it is now <CurrentYear>, you are <Age> years old and so you were born in <YearOfBirth>.
> ```
>
> The message used above must be grammatically correct for the age.
>
> - `<FirstName>` is the users first name.
> - `<CurrentYear>` is the current year
> - `<Age>` is the age in years of the user.
> - `<YearOfBirth>` is the year the user was born in.

and some examples they give:

> ```
> Please enter your first name: Jane
> Hi Jane, please enter your age in years: 1
> Jane, it is now 2018, you are 1 year old and so you were born in 2017.
> ```

and

> ```
> Please enter your first name: Elaine
> Hi Elaine, please enter your age in years: 22
> Elaine, it is now 2018, you are 22 years old and so you were born in 1996.
> ```

I must use the following strings:

> ```
>  "{}, it is now {}, you are {} {} old and so you were born in {}."
>  "year"
>  "s"
> ```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing or tutorial service. Please show your efforts

Comment: @EdChum The `{}` that is referenced refers to string format variables though, so that first google hit is useless. I'd say keep the question open, they are not asking us to write code after all.

Comment: That being said, @sacker, the question contains a lot of instructions. Try to keep it to one answerable question per post, and only provide the information relevant for exactly that.

Comment: @Arne fair enough but this question is still too broad as it's asking for assistance to understand their assignment, so it's not even reached the coding stage and programming is the main thrust of SO

Comment: I have cut back your question text considerably. Please take note of how this was edited; I put your question *on top*, so people reading the post know what to look for. I removed everything from the assignment text that has no bearing on your actual question. Try to do the same in future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your post contains a lot of information and implicit questions, so I will constrain my answer to the explicit one:

> I'm struggling to comprehend how I can have two variables ("year" and "s") being able to go into one {}.

The string that is going to contain either `1 year` or `[more than one] years` is this one: `"{}, it is now {}, you are {} {} old and so you were born in {}."`, and it conveniently contains two format placeholders for the number and "year" or "years" each. Picking a minimal example, this might give you an idea how you can solve your problem:

```
>>> s = "you are {} {} old"
... options = [0, 1, 2, 3]
... for op in options:
...     year_label = "year"
...     if op != 1:
...         year_label += "s"
...     print(s.format(op, year_label))
```

Prints:

```
you are 0 years old
you are 1 year old
you are 2 years old
you are 3 years old
```

There might be more descriptive ways to write this, and I don't know if it will sound right for every possible input. But the important point is that not every placeholder in your output maps to one in- or out-put variable; in this case you need to derive one value based on the input.

Comment: They are instructed to use the strings `"year"` and `"s"`, you use `"year"` and `"years"`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the instructions imply they are expected to use an `if` statement, not a conditional expression. `year_label = "year"`, then `if age > 1: year_label += "s"`.

Comment: I think you are right. Now that I think about it, suggesting ternary operators to someone just picking up python might not have been a good call in the first place. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the placeholders that you need, here is some code:

```
year = 2018



name = input("Please enter your first name: ")

age = input("Hi " + name.title() + " , please enter your age in years: ")

age = int(age)

age_minus_year = (year - age)

if age != 1:

    print("{}, it is now {}, you are {}{} old and so you were born in {}.".format(name.title(), year, age, ' years', str(age_minus_year)))

else:

    print("{}, it is now {}, you are {}{} old and so you were born in {}.".format(name.title(), year, age, ' year', str(age_minus_year)))
```

Here is your output:

```
Please enter your first name: jane
Hi jane, please enter your age in years: 1
Jane, it is now 2018, you are 1 years old and so you were born in 2017.
```

Based on what you mentioned your code required, this code should give you the format that you need. You simply need to use the .format method here. The if statement will simply determine if the print statement should state years or year depending on what the user enters.